# Saving all Inputs entered for display on cout - C++

Tags: c++

I have looked in the forum but can't seem to find anything specific to what I need.

I am writing a program that asks the user to input a number of students. Depending on the number of students they enter they will then have to enter the students name and a series of 10 grades, or pressing 999 to cancel. The program will later have to display all students entered with their average grade. What I have now just overrides the previous inputs and displays the last one entered.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


int main() {

std::string teacherName = "";
std::string classDesignation ="";
int numStudents = 0;
std::string studentName = "";
double grade[10];
double  averageGrade = 0.00;
char letterGrade;

std::cout << "Enter the teacher's name: ";
getline(std::cin, teacherName);

std::cout << "Enter the class designation: ";
getline(std::cin, classDesignation);

std::cout << "Enter the number of students ( 1 or more ): ";
std::cin >> numStudents;
std::cin.ignore();

for (int x = 0; x <= numStudents - 1; x++) {
    std::cout << "Enter the student's name: ";
    getline(std::cin, studentName);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        std::cout << "Enter grade from 0 - 100 or 999 to stop: ";
        std::cin >> grade[i];

        if (grade[i] == 999){
            break;
    }
        averageGrade += grade[i];

        if (averageGrade <= 59){
            letterGrade = 'F';
        }
        if (averageGrade >= 60 || averageGrade <= 69){
            letterGrade = 'D';
        }
        if (averageGrade >= 70 || averageGrade <= 79){
            letterGrade = 'C';
        }
        if (averageGrade >= 80 || averageGrade <= 89){
            letterGrade = 'B';
        }
        if (averageGrade > 90){
            letterGrade = 'A';
        }
    }
}

std::cout << "Teacher: " << teacherName << std::endl;
std::cout << "Class: " << classDesignation << std::endl;
std::cout << "Student Name: " << studentName;
std::cout << std::setw(19) << "Average: " << averageGrade;
std::cout << " Grade: " << letterGrade << std::endl;
std::cout << "Student count: " << numStudents << std::endl;
std::cout << "Student average: " << std::endl;
std::cout << "A's: " << std::endl;
std::cout << "B's: " << std::endl;
std::cout << "C's: " << std::endl;
std::cout << "D's: " << std::endl;
std::cout << "F's: " << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Any tips?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to stick the old inputs into some kind of a container. A `std::vector` ideally.

Comment: Don't you need a small struct for each student?

Comment: @user0042 don't know what that is. Haven't gotten that far yet. Can't use anything not covered by the book yet.

Comment: Hansel, please add this to your question. Any tips? does not qualify. Please take a few seconds to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Hansel Well, then you need at least an array for the student names and letter grades.

Comment: *Any tips?* Yes. See [ask], and then come back and ask a specific question. *Any tips?* isn't one. We also have no idea what limitations you have about what you can or can't use, because we have no idea what *book* you're using or how far along in that book you are, so those restrictions or limitations needed to be included in your post.

Comment: @user0042 Okay awesome, i'll try that. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! **We are not a code writing service.** Please show us what you have tried, and detail what the problem is. Also, learn how to ask good questions for more tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hansel, here's what I think will work.  We'll change this line to get what we want:

```
averageGrade += grade[i];
```

To:

```
//to declarations:
double  averageGradeSum = 0.00;
//then change the line mentioned before to:
averageGradeSum += grade[i];
```

Then:

```
//if for some reason you're indexing starts at 1
averageGrade = averageGradeSum/i; 
//if indexing starts at 0 like usual C++ use: 
averageGrade = averageGradeSum/(i+1);
```

I'm not going to test this.  It should make sense and if I screwed up the syntax it should be an easy google adventure to fix.  Enjoy :)

Comment: sure thing :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you can store them in associative vectors, one for the student name, and one for the average grade. You can also have a doubly linked list of student nodes which would look something like this:

```
struct student
{
    std::string student_name;
    int ave_grade;
    // Head points to the previous student in the array.
    // Tail points to the next student in the array.
    student *head;
    student *tail;
}
```

Declare a struct that everything hangs from to prevent memory leaks: `student list_head;` and each time you have an input, add a new node to the list.